# Is there a method to export the URLs of the open tabs of a Firefox window?

Tags: firefox, url, export, browser-tabs

If I have a Firefox window open that contains 10 tabs, is there a way in Firefox or by a plug-in to get the URLs of those 10 tabs as a text file or some other format?

Right now if I want to do this I need to copy the URL of tab A, paste it somewhere, move to tab B, and repeat.  I could also bookmark all the tabs into a folder and export that, but that seems like such a hassle.

If there is no such method, could someone point me to some documents that describe the basics of writing a Firefox plug-in.  I am willing to write this myself if there is no "standard" way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found an add-on called Send Tab URLs that copies the URLs of all open tabs with the intention of sending them by email to someone.  This add-on also allows the target of the URLs to be the clipboard as well as email so this solves my problem 100%.

<s>https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4437</s>
*(The add-on is no longer available)*

Comment: unfortunately this is end of life with Firefox 57. Has anyone found an alternative?

Comment: @semtex41 Yes there is. Here it is: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-all-tab-urls-we/ Its called "Copy All Tab URLs WE"

Comment: Also, another: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-tabs-urls-and-titles/?src=search

Comment: fwiw the code is available at https://github.com/aecreations/sendtaburls/ (or at [SWH](https://archive.softwareheritage.org/browse/origin/https://github.com/aecreations/sendtaburls/directory/))

Comment: This add-on is simple yet flexible - allows to set up your own formatting of the list and select tabs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/get-tabs-infos/

Answer (score 90):

Go to Tools > Options.

In the General tab look for the **Use Current Pages** button in the Startup  section. When you click on the **Use Current Pages** button, all the URLs of the pages open in different tabs are copied to the Home Page text box with a pipe delimiter. Copy the text to get all the URLs.

The keyboard shortcut to simulate clicking on the **Use Current Pages** button is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (tested in Firefox 14)

Comment: This action can also be easily reversed, just hit ctrl-z to undo the change and whatever was in the textbox previously will be restored.  Now you don't have to install a plugin.

Comment: This is not working for me when trying to save a huge session of 300+ tabs in about 7 Windows. There seems to be a limit to this trick in terms of tab numbers, beware

Comment: T.O.C. = Table of Contents! Neat! Works in Firefox 17.0.9 on Windows.

Comment: Nice answer. `Alt+E+N+C` for any other Linux users. :)

Comment: For Mac users, go to Firefox > Preferences (the Tools menu has no entry Options).

Comment: This only includes tabs in the current tab group.

Comment: This method works wonderfully, but you'll have to do it for each window. It also doesn't grab pinned tabs, so you'll have to do those separately as well.

Comment: @Tanath `This only includes tabs in the current tab group` Thankfully. Otherwise it would mix all groups together.

Comment: While Firefox doesn't handle a drag and drop of this string directly into the browser, it does handle a drag and drop of the URLs with a newline separator. `sed "s/|/\n/g"`

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer. Let me get this straight, you are temporarily setting your homepage to a string containing current tabs separated by pipes (which won't look very nice when psting into an email or doc). You copy the URL, and then undo to set your homepage back to how you had it. What happens if you forget that step? Rook's answer is a much a better logical method to get all tab URLs.

Comment: As of version 114.0.2, 'Use Current Pages' is located at: Settings>Home>Home>New Windows and Tabs>Homepage and new windows>menu item 'Custom URLs...'

Answer (score 23):

No need to export anything.

Just save all the tabs in a folder (you already know how to do that), right click on folder, copy. Open notepad, paste.
Voila. All URL's of bookmarks in that folder.

Comment: Yes, that does work, but I was thinking more along the lines of having an option in a plug-in menu or the context menu that would put the URLs into my clipboard.  Then I won't have to create, view, and delete intermediate bookmark folders.

Comment: Sorry, don't know of any plugin which would do that. It is a rather unusual request (I still can't see why do you need something like that...). Anyways, you got one way now ... this one takes about 6 clicks ... the fastest I know, sorry.

Comment: Right click on tab, bookmark all tabs, ok, right click on dir, copy ... url's are in clipboard ... 5 clicks.

Comment: Yeah you are right about it's unusualness.  I think I'm going to look up references on writing Firefox plug-ins.  I want it to be 2 clicks dammit!  Thanks though.

Comment: This may help you :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon     | You still haven't told what do you need something like that for ? ;)

Comment: This is not so unusal a problem. I was looking for the very same thing. I have 50+ tabs openon my work pc from things I find in my lunch break I either want to remember or come back and read in depth later. i want to export and store so I can open at home and browse at leisure. +1 for question

Comment: This was very quick. The steps are CTRL-SHIFT-D to bookmark all tabs -> right click on new bookmark group -> Copy -> Paste into email. Very nicely it pastes as text with the url as a link so you know what each url actually is.

Comment: @ianfuture .- Sorry, for the fantastically late reply, but do you know of https://pinboard.in/ ? It's a very nice bookmark system which you can access from both work and home. Costs like a few dollars at the beginning, and then - that's it. Just for info.

Answer (score 12):

From the [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/96739/is-there-a-method-to-export-the-urls-of-the-open-tabs-of-a-firefox-window#comment98020_96744) by @Rook:

- Right click on any tab
- Choose "bookmark all tabs"
- Right click on the new folder
- Choose "copy"

Now the URLs are in clipboard.

Comment: Some notes & hints: **(1)** When you choose ”*bookmark all tabs*“, Firefox will open a new window asking you to define the *name* and the *location* of the folder to be created. **(2)** The URLs in the clipboard will be separated by newlines. The first line will contains the previously defined *folder name*. **(3)** about ”*right-clicking on the new folder*“: You can right-click not only in the ”*Library*“ (`Ctrl+Shift+O`), but also in the *Bookmarks Toolbar* (given you created it there), the *Bookmarks Sidebar* (`Ctrl+B`) or even the drop-down menu of the *menu bar*.

Comment: @ aparente001: **PS:** I suppose you are referring to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/96739/is-there-a-method-to-export-the-urls-of-the-open-tabs-of-a-firefox-window#comment98020_96744) by *Rook*. **PPS:** you've got a typo in ”Chooseookmark“ ;)

Comment: Press `CTRL+SHIFT+D` in Firefox (Windows) if the option "Bookmark all tabs" is not there when you right click a tab.

Answer (score 9):

An open source plugin to do the job: [Copy as Markdown](https://github.com/chitsaou/copy-as-markdown). Added benefits: works on both Firefox and Chrome, and it exports with Markdown formatting.

> **Copy as Markdown for Chrome & Firefox**
>
> Do you often type Markdown code
>   manually for a link or image, or even all tabs in a window, and feel
>   tired? Copy as Markdown can help you!
>
> **Features**
>
> Copy as Markdown is a browser extension helps you copy the following
>   things as Markdown to your system clipboard:
>
> - Current Tab as Link
> - A Link in the Page
> - An Image in the Page
> - An Image that is wrapped with a Link
> - All Tabs as a List of Links
> - Highlighted Tabs as a List of Links

Excerpt from the project's readme.

It can be added to Firefox from its [Add-Ons listing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-as-markdown/).

Comment: Thanks. I had written my own bookmarklet to do this for the current tab but this extension provides more useful features.

Answer (score 7):

The addon in the accepted answer is no longer available [since](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/old-firefox-add-ons-will-stop-working-in-firefox-57-end-of-2017/) the [update](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/) to [Firefox 57](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/firefox-57-useful-webextensions-and-legacy-extensions-alternatives/18083/3) in [2017](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/09/28/webextensions-in-firefox-57/).

Fortunately, there are many addons that provide the desired functionality of saving the URLs of open tabs to a text file. For example (in order of first release):

- [Save Tab URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-tab-urls/), first released December 6, 2017

  - https://github.com/mnba/save-tabs
- [Export Tabs URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-tabs-urls-and-titles/), first released July 1, 2019

  - https://github.com/alct/export-tabs-urls
- [Save Tab URLs to Markdown](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-tab-urls-to-markdown/), first released September 11, 2019

  - https://github.com/Lewiscowles1986/save-tabs-as-markdown-ff-chrome-poc

I wanted HTML output and timestamps, so I made my own:

- [Save tabs to HTML file](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-tabs-to-html-file/)

  - https://github.com/nbeaver/save-tabs-as-html

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the last add-on.)

Answer (score 5):

```
#Test in Firefox 5.0
$sessionStoreFile = "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\sessionstore-backups\recovery.js"
$sessionStoreFileExists = Test-Path $sessionStoreFile
If($sessionStoreFileExists -eq $False) {
    #Test in Firefox 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0
    $sessionStoreFile = "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\sessionstore.js"
}
(Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Raw -Path $sessionStoreFile).Trim('()') | ConvertFrom-Json |
Select -Expand Windows | Select -Expand Tabs | 
Where { !$_.hidden } | ForEach { @($_.Entries)[-1] } | 
Select Url, Title | Export-Csv -Path $CsvFile  -Encoding UTF8  -NoTypeInformation
```

You can download detail SQL script from [how to export all URLs of Firefox tabs at once(PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-export-all-URLs-of-01af744b)

Answer (score 5):

Give a try to [Export Tabs URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-tabs-urls-and-titles/) (Firefox 48+)

It lets you either copy the current opened URLs list (optionally including their title) to clipboard  or export it to a timestamped file.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider a similar add-on with different options, [CopyAllURLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/934); especially if mailing is not a priority. -Isn't that 2 clicks ? It's in the context menu. [That linked page also lists 'alternative solutions']

Comment: Sheesh, this add-on is now out of date.....what solution will even work for this problem?

Comment: you can download the latest version from the [homepage](http://www.plasser.net/copyallurls/).

Comment: @DJCrashdummy that is generally a bad idea.... addons on the site get checked for stability, malware etc

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Copy Urls Expert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-urls-expert/). It adds a menu item when I right-click on a tab. There are options to copy all URLs in the current window, in the current tab group, or all tabs; and also to open URLs from the clipboard. The URLs are just separated by newlines. I appreciated the simplicity of this approach, as compared to alternatives like Send Tab URLs which includes the title of each page along with the URL. "Copy Urls Expert" is a rewrite of [CopyAllURLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copyallurls/), which is defunct.

Comment: I'm also a fan of this, but Firefox Quantum ... reeee. Copy Urls Expert is one of the reasons I didn't update, yet. With the script in my answer that is solved for me, but I also need a replacement for Menu Wizard and Tab Mix Plus.

Comment: @mxmlnkn Yeah I just downgraded by installing a Firefox ESR binary. So I can type in this box with "It's All Text!".

Answer (score 3):

This is not an addon, but for my own convenience I wrote a bash function if you are not afraid of the command line and if you are using Linux:

```bsh
getOpenTabs(){
    local profile=$( sed -n -r '/^Path=/,/^Default=1/{ s|^Path=(.*)|\1|p; }' 
        "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini" )
    # https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4/blob/master/src/dejsonlz4.c
    dejsonlz4 "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/$profile/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4" |
        jq -c '.windows[].tabs[].entries[-1].url' |
        sed 's|^"||; s|"$||;' |
        xclip -selection c
}
```

On calling this function with `getOpenTabs` it reads the current session backup from the default profile folder extracts it using [`dejsonlz4`](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4/), which you need to install for this function, and saves the links to the clipboard.
Packages needed (besides dejsonlz4): `jq`, `sed`, `xclip`

Comment: I think `jq -r ...` obviates the need to strip the double-quotes. On Ubuntu, you can use `lz4jsoncat` from `lz4json` package.

Answer (score 3):

None of the present answers work for me (Firefox on Linux) and I didn't want to install an addon. This should work on all Operating Systems, I think.

1. Right-click on a tab and click on Select all tabs
2. Right-click on a tab and click on Bookmark tabs...
3. Choose a name for the bookmark folder where you want to store them (e.g. My tabs)
4. Press Alt to see the menu and choose Bookmarks-All bookmarks (Ctrl-Shift-O)
5. Click on Import and Backup->Backup
6. Choose where you want to back them up

When you want to restore in a new Firefox simply do step 4 and choose restore in step 5.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to export all opened tabs from FIREFOX
 is  "CTRL + SHIFT +D" or ALT + B and then Bookmark all tabs
and save as folder bookmark in Bookmark Manager  --> then export  as HTML

Comment: Bookmark all tabs??? What about the existing bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [URL Lister](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-lister/) for a couple of occasions. It is a simple addon that adds an option in "Tools". It then displays all open tabs' URL's in an editable text area.

It allows to export the list (by copying it to the clipboard) as plain text, HTML anchors or as a bulleted list.

It looks (by visual comparison of the available screenshots) similar to the [beforementioned](https://superuser.com/a/99152/228536) Send Tab URLs, with the differences being the lack of e-mail support and with the existence of the editable text area.

[image]

Comment: In contrast to *Send Tab Urls*, *URL Lister* doesn't work with Firefox 56.

Answer (score 1):

As the second choice you mentioned putting the links into a text file.   That method allows you to create documentation for research, and to email the links with titles, and descriptions (or other meta data), creating your own choices of what you want to copy and how you want it formatted.   You can use [**Multiple Tab Handler** (Firefox addon)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multiple-tab-handler/).  I will just show what I use for copying into email, as I think creating an unordered list of links with buried urls in hypertext would not show up well here.   The first two pages did not have descriptions, so I threw in one of my own.  If emailing I might manually boldface the titles, and remove the "::" when there is no description.

[**Tabbed Browsing in Firefox**](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/tabs.htm) :: Tabbed browsing in Firefox lets you load multiple web pages into separate tabs within the same browser window

*Using MTH works well for creating documentation in [Evernote](https://evernote.com/), useful if you work on multiple systems or want your notes available anywhere. 
To help you with some examples of setting up MTH with a variety of choices see
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/multiple_tab_handler.txt*

Comment: I object to edit done to the above, which is well intended, but destroys the content.   MTH does not generate rich text format, so it cannot generate what is shown above.  For something similar to the above one would  have to use a different set of output and put that output through an online editor before pasting into an email.   The example included a link to this very question so that one can see specifically what might be generated, plus two more links (still included) that not only serve to show in the example but as links to additional content of interest.  Severe limitations on answers.

Comment: Answer is supposed to include @djcrashdummy, -at-Hennes, and -at-duDE.  At the time I did not have enough points to post nice links which would only have applied to the first list for Multiple Tab Handler within the large paragraph.   And now I lack (a few thousand) points to be able to reverse an incorrect edit.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab for this purpose:

```
pip install brotab
brotab install
```

Install the web extension as well: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brotab/

Restart Firefox, and you can pipe `brotab list` to a file:

```
brotab list > current-tabs.txt
```

You can also parse the output with e.g awk:

```
brotab list | awk -F'\t' '{
    print "Downloading "$2
    system("curl --silent --output \""$2"\" \""$3"\"")
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I happened to try dozens of Firefox addons that copy/export tabs URLs lately.
Searching on [Mozilla Firefox extensions catalog](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/), at the moment I write, one of the most popular addon is
[Export Tabs URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-tabs-urls-and-titles/) and in fact it is not bad but, yet, digging a little bit more I think there are better alternatives, so now I'll suggest the ones I prefer.

First of all, a due premise: this makes sense only if you're dealing with lots of tabs, indeed, the addons I'm going to suggest do not distinguish current selected tab, they always take into account ALL the tabs you have opened in that moment in a Firefox window.

That said, here comes my favorite: [Save Tab URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-tab-urls/).

This addon adds a new "Copy URLs (all tabs)" command into tab context menu and a tool button that makes a popup show up when clicked, the latter being the truly interesting stuff; indeed, once the popup is opened, you'll see a text-area, listing title and URLs of all the currently opened tabs, and commands that will let you filter listed entries, even using regex for it. Besides letting you copy to clipboard the text-area content (btw, you can also edit that if you want), you can as well save/export as a text file or it is possible for you to paste http(s) links in the text area and click on the provided command button to open them up back in new tabs (kinda as when you open all entries in a bookmarked folder). All of this is presented in pretty clean GUI.
Both the tabs context menu and the popup commands always take into account all the tabs opened on the actual Firefox window (so no option for the single tab, as I said in the premise) and also keep in mind, btw, that this will be limited to current window only opened tabs (always including pinned ones) and if you have more than one Firefox windows opened, the tabs in others windows won't be taken into account.
(I wish this one had some little more of improvements, like for example the option to copy only current tab URL/title via context menu, an option to copy only URLs without titles and adding at least Markdown -and maybe Json- format; with those features added this extension would be simply perfect for me!)

[image: Highlight on Save Tab URLs Firefox addon]

P.S.
*Save Tab URLs* seems having a very similar alter ego (a kind of clone tbh) the only difference with it seems it lists tabs URLs only and no titles: [URLs List](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/urls-list/).
And, in case you're looking for an even minimalistic equivalent (just copy or open tab URLs): [tabs2txt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabs2txt/)

Notable mentions:

- [Copy/Paste and Save tabs list](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/paste-site-list/)
  It provide more or less the same features of the previous one thus it has a little messy GUI compared to it and it lacks text-area contents filtering and exporting to text file capabilities but kinda provide themes (lets you change color combination choosing beetween 2 dark ones and a light one) the option to add line-breaks between entries or not and to include or not titles with URLs. It also provide a kind of internal bookmarks system called "Saved lists".
- [Bulk URL Opener](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/bulkurlopener)
  It has a nice GUI with dark/light theme, lets you save URLs lists in a similar fashion of the previous addon I talked about (I think the previous one has a better approach with that imho) but does not include tab titles in any way, just URLs.

Just like in the case of Save Tab URLs, both of them let you export the tabs list to a text file with few mouse clicks on some buttons but lack to provide other than titles+URLs and support no custom formats, if you need that you must use other Firefox addons such as [Copy URL To Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/url2clipboard/), [CopyTabTitleUrl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copytabtitleurl/) or [Copy Selected Tabs to Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-selected-tabs-to-clipboar/) (which imho are all better alternatives to the more popular [Copy All Tab Urls](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-all-tab-urls-we/)) but they only let you copy to clipboard, so if you need to export the list to a file you'll have to create it by yourself and then paste the list in it and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Exact steps described are for Linux, for Windows one might try to look at other answers in the link below (there are some e.g. using Python).

One can get tab URLs + titles list in text using https://superuser.com/a/1563665/1264656. Sample output:

```
"https://www.quora.com/Can-VR-headsets-emulate-having-a-large-monitor-for-your-laptop"
"Can VR headsets emulate having a large monitor for your laptop? - Quora"

"https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/9qet3j/can_you_use_a_vr_headset_as_a_monitor_for_games/"
"(5) Can you use a VR headset as a \"monitor\" for games that do not have VR support and it will function as a display without headtracking? : oculus"
```

In case that link changes, I copy main part below:

```
lz4jsoncat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default*/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 \
  | jq '.["windows"] | .[0] | .["tabs"] | .[] | .["entries"] | .[0] | .url,.title' \
  | grep -v 'New Tab' | grep -v 'about:newtab' | sed 's/"http/\n"http/g'
```

Relies on Firefox' "backup" in case of crashing, stored in `recovery.jsonlz4` file in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile_name/sessionstore-backups` (that is in Linux, Windows is similar).

Files in `sessionstore-backups` can be used to transfer tabs from one PC to another (or backup). One need to abnormally terminate Firefox (not via build-in Quit) and replace contents of `sessionstore-backups` (4 small files on my PC) with such files backed up previously (or from another PC/profile), then Firefox starts with tabs from that folder.

Tested for Firefox 93 / 86 (yes, bringing files from newer to older too, whole profile from newer did not work on older).

To terminate Firefox in Linux:
`pkill firefox& || pkill GeckoMain`

Answer (score 1):

Python code to extract URLs from `recovery.jsonlz4` adapted from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1297930) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Tblue/62ff47bef7f894e92ed5):

```
import json
import lz4.block

# Path to recovery.jsonlz4 on Windows is something like C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profile}\sessionstore-backups\recovery.jsonlz4.
with open(r'path/to/recovery.jsonlz4', 'rb') as f:
    f.read(8) # Skip magic number.
    compressed_binary_contents = f.read()
    binary_contents = lz4.block.decompress(compressed_binary_contents)
    contents = binary_contents.decode()
    data = json.loads(contents)

for window in data['windows']:
    for tab in window['tabs']:
        page_history = tab['entries']
        url = page_history[-1]['url']
        print(url)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox 57 (Quantum), the following Plugin seems to have similiar functionality to "Send Tab URLs" but honestly isnt as clean with the URL and Title:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/copy-as-markdown/

But it works. 
I hope the author of "Send Tab URLs" updates his plugin as WebExtensions.

Comment: You can use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-all-tab-urls-we/

Answer (score -1):

CLICK the "ICON" and drag to desktop.  (The quickest way :)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use "Tab Groups" you can export/import all your tabs easily as a bookmarks

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so. For example, a brief explanation of what tab groups are, and how to export them.

Answer (score -3):

follow up to tazo's suggestion:

drag the "icon" (earth or lock or whatever) onto a Word doc.  the URL appears at whatever point the cursor was left at.

this isn't a good solution for the original question, as you still have to go to each tab, but at least it's slightly faster than right-clicking in the address bar, copying, and then pasting in a document.  it might also be a quick shortcut for those times when you just need to include the URL from a tab with some other text.

note:  the first time i tried this, it appeared in the Word doc as different text.  the text *was* a hyperlink, and when i opened to edit the hyperlink, the URL it pointed to was the tab i'd tried to drag over.  i don't know where that text came from.  my guess is it might have been the last bit of text i'd copied and it was sitting on the clipboard.

note2:  this didn't work for Notepad.

note3:  CopyAllURLs and URL Lister are not available for version 42.0 (or, as of sometime in 2014).
Copy Links seems to still be an option.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-links/