# How to save open tabs's URLs to a file?

Tags: browser, tabs

Say if I have about 25 tabs open in my browser. Is there a way I could:

- a) save all those URLs to a file and
- b) Start a browser instance to load all of these URLs/

Browsers: Firefox/chrome (latest versions as of today).

If there's a browser that can do this, please do point that out as well

Comment: IDK about saving the tabs, but to open them up from a newline separated file on linux, `firefox &; cat file.txt | xargs firefox`.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/96739/58026

Comment: OP asks how to open saved tabs which the so-called "Duplicate question" does not ask. So if @Lawrence's answer does not answer your needs here's how I open saved tabs : Run a script with `for line in $(cat $file); do firefox -new-tab "$line" & 2>/dev/null; sleep 2; done` where `$file' is the wanted text file that (SaveMyTabs)[https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/save-my-tabs/] auto-write. Just have to remove the "Window" column first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Chrome, [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en) allows you to export a session's links to text/CSV and gives a few different options of showing titles and/or the windows selected.

You can also **save sessions**, which can be loaded later (reloads all the urls you saved). This sounds like what you are trying to achieve.

[image: Select export option]

[image: Export links]

There is no manual export to file option, but with the export text, you can save the links your self, then import them later with their import button.

[image: Import links from text input]

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest the same. But I use Session Buddy mostly because I have found Chrome's built-in tab saving and restoring to be far less reliable.

Comment: Definitely. `Continue where I left off` and `Restore` can be nightmares.

Comment: This is awesome !

Answer (score 1):

Using Firefox, if you right click on the tabs, then click `Bookmark All Tabs`, then you could then re-open all of those tabs within firefox by right clicking on bookmark folder and then click on `Open All in Tabs`