# How to move all open tabs from Safari to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, safari

In my case I have many tabs opened in Safari and I want to move to Firefox. I know I can note down all the url in a text file and open all of them again one by one in another browser. But I'm looking for any shortcut way.

Comment: Create bookmarks for the open tabs, export the bookmarks, then import the exported bookmarks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a method to export the URLs of the open tabs of a Firefox window?](http://superuser.com/questions/96739/is-there-a-method-to-export-the-urls-of-the-open-tabs-of-a-firefox-window)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @adaaaam Latest version on OSX

Answer (score 7):

You could use the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    set newTabURLs to takeSafariTabURLs() of me
    repeat with tabURL in newTabURLs
        open location tabURL
        delay 1
    end repeat

end tell

on takeSafariTabURLs()
    set tabURLs to {}
    tell application "Safari"
        repeat with w in windows
            if name of w is not "" then --in case of zombie windows
                repeat with t in tabs of w
                    set tabURL to URL of t
                    set the end of tabURLs to tabURL

                end repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        return tabURLs
    end tell
end takeSafariTabURLs
```

Comment: very helpful, you saved my time. thank you! commenting from FF, searched in Safari :D

Comment: Life saver!! Also ram saver (with help of AutoTabDiscard).. just saved 38 GB of RAM \o/

Answer (score 2):

I tried following what Ramhound has mentioned, and it turned out to be very helpful. I saved all the bookmarks in a folder in Safari, and then imported the bookmarks in Firefox. It was just a simple process.

Answer (score 2):

Minor changes to preserve windows. I put a gist of this as well...if others want to improve it. see https://gist.github.com/amanuel/81e70673b057687e904a248218c50ce2

```
    tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    set safariWindows to getSafariWindows() of me
    repeat with w in safariWindows
        set newTabURLs to takeSafariTabURLs(w) of me
        repeat with tabURL in newTabURLs
            open location tabURL
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell

on getSafariWindows()
    set safariWindows to {}
    tell application "Safari"
        repeat with w in windows
            if name of w is not "" then --in case of zombie windows
                set the end of safariWindows to w
            end if
        end repeat
        return safariWindows
    end tell
end getSafariWindows

on takeSafariTabURLs(w)
    set tabURLs to {}
    tell application "Safari"
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            set tabURL to URL of t
            set the end of tabURLs to tabURL
        end repeat
        return tabURLs
    end tell
end takeSafariTabURLs
```